# Update one column with multiple rows returned from sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have found lots of material on this but I cannot find anything specific to my scenario to help me fix my issue and get rid of the error,

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

The part of my stored procedure I'm having problems with is as follows.

```
set @strSql = 'update ' + @tableName 
+ ' set unique_subs_'+@FieldName + ' = (select isnull(COUNT(distinct  a.wr_unique_subs),0) 
from tbl_Cluster_Subs_revenue a, tbl_Cell_info b 
where a.wr_cell_id = b.CI group by b.Cluster_Name)'
exec(@strSql)
```

Would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is unclear?  The subquery is returning more than one value.  You need to choose one of them.  I would also recommend using standard `join` syntax, rather than implicit joins int he `where` clause.

You could fix this by using `top 1`:

```
update ' + @tableName + '
    set unique_subs_'+@FieldName + ' = (select top 1 isnull(COUNT(distinct  a.wr_unique_subs),0) 
                                        from tbl_Cluster_Subs_revenue a join
                                             tbl_Cell_info b 
                                             on a.wr_cell_id = b.CI
                                        group by b.Cluster_Name
                                       );
```

(Just because you are putting the SQL in a string does not mean it has to be poorly formatted.  SQL Server allows end of line characters in strings.)

I am guessing, though, that you might want something like this:

```
update ' + @tableName + '
    set unique_subs_'+@FieldName + ' = (select COUNT(distinct  a.wr_unique_subs)
                                        from tbl_Cluster_Subs_revenue a join
                                             tbl_Cell_info b 
                                             on a.wr_cell_id = b.CI
                                         where Cluster_Name = ''' + @FieldName + '''
                                         )
```

You don't actually need the `isnull()`, because `count()` returns `0` if no rows match.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a place of isnull function as below:

```
set @strSql = 'update ' + @tableName 
+ ' set unique_subs_'+@FieldName + ' = isnull((select COUNT(distinct  a.wr_unique_subs)
from tbl_Cluster_Subs_revenue a, tbl_Cell_info b 
where a.wr_cell_id = b.CI group by b.Cluster_Name),0) '
exec(@strSql)
```